# Magento 1.8.1 - Remove FedEx Insurance

Tags: magento, fedex

The default backend Magento 1.8.1 FedEx setting do not allow for the option of removing insurance and forces the default value of the item to be fully insured.

```
    'Version' => $this->getVersionInfo(),
        'RequestedShipment' => array(
            'DropoffType'   => $r->getDropoffType(),
            'ShipTimestamp' => date('c'),
            'PackagingType' => $r->getPackaging(),
            'TotalInsuredValue' => array(
                'Amount'  => $r->getValue(),
                'Currency' => $this->getCurrencyCode()
```

I am trying to get the 'Amount' to be set at $99 (all shipments get a default $100 coverage if damaged). Should I add the following line:

'Amount'  => 99,

Please advise :)

Comment: Hi, I wanted to comment that the "TotalInsuredValue" node is not actually an insurance of any type. This is the declared value or cost of the commodities in the package. FedEx does not provides insurance of any kind. Check FedEx Developer Guide for more detail.

Comment: Agree'd FedEx provides no actual insurance. How do I then force set the "Declared Value" to $100USD for all shipments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to remove the insurance value so my solution should be suitable as well for you.

As pointed out by @Chris  you should rewrite this file `app/code/core/Mage/USA/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php`

and change the method `_formRateRequest`

**How to Remove the insurance**
comment the code as shown below:

( line 330 )

```
 'RequestedShipment' => array(
                'DropoffType'   => $r->getDropoffType(),
                'ShipTimestamp' => date('c'),
                'PackagingType' => $r->getPackaging(),
//                'TotalInsuredValue' => array(
//                    'Amount'  => $r->getValue(),
//                    'Currency' => $this->getCurrencyCode()
//                ),
                'Shipper' => array(
                    'Address' => array(
                        'PostalCode'  => $r->getOrigPostal(),
                        'CountryCode' => $r->getOrigCountry()
                    )
                ),
```

**AND** ( line 380 )

```
       if ($purpose == self::RATE_REQUEST_GENERAL) {
//            $ratesRequest['RequestedShipment']['RequestedPackageLineItems'][0]['InsuredValue'] = array(
//                'Amount'  => $r->getValue(),
//                'Currency' => $this->getCurrencyCode()
//            );
        }
```

**Change the amount**
if you want to use a fix value instead of commenting the line you should just set the 'Amount' to a fix value

Suppose you want a fixed amount of 100$

Change the code as shown below:

Add this variable on the top of the method

```
$amount = 100;
```

( line 330 )

```
 'RequestedShipment' => array(
                'DropoffType'   => $r->getDropoffType(),
                'ShipTimestamp' => date('c'),
                'PackagingType' => $r->getPackaging(),
                'TotalInsuredValue' => array(
                'Amount'  => $amount),
                'Currency' => $this->getCurrencyCode()
                ),
                'Shipper' => array(
                    'Address' => array(
                        'PostalCode'  => $r->getOrigPostal(),
                        'CountryCode' => $r->getOrigCountry()
                    )
                ),
```

**AND** ( line 380 )

```
       if ($purpose == self::RATE_REQUEST_GENERAL) {
           $ratesRequest['RequestedShipment']['RequestedPackageLineItems'][0]['InsuredValue'] = array(
               'Amount'  => $amount,
               'Currency' => $this->getCurrencyCode()
            );
        }
```

Comment: 'Amount' => $r->100,     Would that be accurate or remove the $r? Thank you so much for your help :) I have tried this several times and I must be doing something incorrectly.

Comment: I have added more detail. basically you need to put instead of `$r->getValue()`, your value ( ex. 100 )

Comment: please vote/accept the answer ... this is how it works StackOverflow :)

Comment: That seems to be correct, however it hasn't fixed my issue with Magento. It still has not lowered the shipping rate and appears to be requesting the full item cart amount opposed to a fixed 100$

Answer (score 0):

Setting Amount to 99 will work as intended.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working... I have tried it several ways and it still seems to pull the value of the item only. (IE the $r->getValue()

Comment: Check line 379 in app/code/core/Mage/USA/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php.

Answer (score 0):

Following @WonderLand instructions worked like a charm! Took me a week initially to figure out how to remove the declared value from the rate calculation. I simply edited the file app/code/core/Mage/USA/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php, did a search in dreamweaver for `$r->getValue()` and replaced all instances with 100.

SIDE NOTE: For whatever it's worth all of my caches under magento configuration were already disabled. Not sure if it matters, but it didn't require me to clear/empty any caches to see the changes immediately on the frontend.